# Argparse add option strings

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

That question will be strange in some point...

I'm trying to add the option strings in the parser after adding one argument.

For example

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument(dest = 'myvar')
p._actions[1].option_strings = ['-foo']
p.parse_args('-foo 1')
```

This example doesn't work, it says:

```
: error: the following arguments are required: -foo
```

Even though I'm supplying the argument...

Anyone know why this is occurring?

Is there some way to add the option strings after the add_argument method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the [source code of argparse](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py), I found you also have to register the action by the option string it has:

```python
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument(dest = 'myvar')
p._actions[1].option_strings = ['-foo']

# You also need to do this
p._option_string_actions['-foo'] = p._actions[1]

args = p.parse_args(['-foo', '100'])
print('myvar is', args.myvar)  # myvar is 1
```

Note the change when calling `parse_args`.

I hope this help!!

Comment: I know this behaviour, and how the argparse acts using this syntax. Although my question is a little bit more complicated. I want to add the option strings after adding one argument....

Comment: @kaihami, the source code of argparse gave me the answer. I edited my answer above and think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @kaihami The main problem is that you are trying to hack on argparse and thus, you were bypassing its registration mechanism and all the setup it does

Comment: Thank you indeed I forgot about p._option_strings_actions!

Comment: Please, @kaihami , mark my answer as the right one if you think it helped you. I will really appreciate it. Thanks